# pytube takes too long to stream a video in Android

Tags: python, android, pytube, chaquopy, android-thread

I am using *pytube* to stream a video in Android, with the help of **chaquopy**.

***videofile.py***

```
from pytube import YouTube
def video(link):
    yt = YouTube(f'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + link)
    stream_url = yt.streams.get_highest_resolution().url
    return stream_url
```

***VideoActivityPy.java***

```
progressBar = findViewById(R.id.pro);
videoView = findViewById(R.id.videoview);
new Thread(() -> {
    try {
        if (!Python.isStarted()) {
            Python.start(new AndroidPlatform(VideoActivityPy.this));
        }
        python = Python.getInstance();
        pyScript = python.getModule("videofile");
        videoUri = pyScript.callAttr("video", MyData.videoLink);
        runOnUiThread(() -> {
            videoView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                                  View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(videoUri.toString());
            videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
            MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(VideoActivityPy.this);
            mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
            mediaController.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
            videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
            videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    videoView.start();
                }
            });
       });
    }
    catch (com.chaquo.python.PyException pyException) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Toast.makeText(VideoActivityPy.this, "Check your internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Toast.makeText(VideoActivityPy.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}).start();
```

At first, I had written the code without using Thread, but the app was not responding. So, I used Thread. Now the app works, the video loads, but it takes about 40-50 seconds to start the video (the video is 1.5 hours long though). Is there any way to reduce the loading time?

Note: I have downloaded **.tar.gz** file from *PyPI*, changed the built-in code of pytube, and then written the gradle as below:

```
python {
    buildPython "C:/Python38/python.exe"
    pip {
        install "pytube-15.0.0.tar.gz"
    }
}
```

I changed the **var_regex** in ***cipher.py***

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code has two phases:

- Getting the URL with pytube
- Streaming from the URL to the `videoView` (pytube and Python are not involved)

It's not possible to guess which of these is causing the delay, so try adding some [`Log`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log) statements within your code (or in Python, `print` statements). Then the timestamps in the log will reveal which lines are taking the most time.